# incompatible type for argument in Objective-C - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: objective-c, types, parameter-passing

I can't spot what I'm doing wrong here.

I have 2 classes, harness and audioplayer.

In the audioplayer header I have declared my function like so.

```
- (void) loadAudioFileIntoMemory:(NSURL *)address channel:(int) value row:(int) value2;
```

// In the audioplayer implmentation file my function is like so.

```
- (void) loadAudioFileIntoMemory:(NSURL *)address channel:(int)value row:(int)value2
{

 //NSLog(address);
}
```

When I try to call the function in the following way I get an incompatible type for argument error. (audioPlayer is a member of harness by the way and the line below is from harness)

```
[self.audioPlayer loadAudioFileIntoMemory:rawurls[count] channel:0 row:0];
```

**EDIT 1 for clarity**

This is how I am defining my raw url array

```
rawurls= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:16];
    // Create the URLs for the source audio files. The URLForResource:withExtension: method is new in iOS 4.0.
    NSURL *loop0   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"FHP_EFFECT25_C.mp3"
                                                withExtension: @"mp3"];

[rawurls addObject:loop0]
```

Comment: This should be tagged `[objective-c]`, not `[c]`

Comment: looks like obj-c, rather than c

Comment: What's the type of rawurls - NSURL** or NSURL*?

Comment: @ alex. Could you please explain the difference to me? I wasnt aware there was 2 types of NSURL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not access the objets in an NSArray with C style subscripts.

You need to do this:

```
[self.audioPlayer loadAudioFileIntoMemory:[rawurls objectAtIndex: count] channel:0 row:0];
```

Comment: Thankyou!!! The code I'm trying to write uses c and obj-c. I've never done c before so my head is getting a little muddled at times

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are written your code as is rawurls was of type `**NSURL` - i.e. an array of pointers to `NSURL`s.  In fact from your final example, it's of type `NSArray`.

Subscript operators don't work on `NSArray`s - this is *Objective-C* not *c++*.

Here's how to [subscript an NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html):

```
(NSURL*)[rawurls objectAtIndex:count]
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement your suggestion